# using reset_index() in python to create additional rows based on date range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, reset

i have a large-ish data set with rows like:

```
RecordID    CarName   ShopArrive      ShopLeave NameOfShop  Month   Year    ShopDays
101         Vehic056    08/22/2019  09/03/2019  Joes         08     2015      13
```

i would like to use reset_index() in pandas or something like it to duplicate the ~13 records to represent the 13 days this car spent in the shop by rows.

new to python, experienced in SQL, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: for instance, i've tried this, but got an unsupported operand type error for the time even though it's in datetime64 as type:

````````````````````
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index, df['ShopDapys'])]
df['ShopArrival'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),unit='d')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 2):

The method df.reset_index() will not modify the number of rows. You need to look for something similar to [df.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df = df.assign(dates_in_shop=
    [[row.ShopArrive + i for i in range(row.ShopDays + 1)]
        for row in df.itertuples()])
df = df.explode('dates_in_shop').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thanks, @RichieV - this is super helpful. although i was able to fix my code from above (recast the right array to make it datetime64) and the number of rows was expanded in my dataframe.